# How to use Zend Cache with SimpleXML objects?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm trying to cache the user timeline of a Twitter feed using Zend_Service_Twitter which returns its results as a SimpleXML object. Unfortunately the regular serialize functions (which Zend Cache uses) don't play nice with SimpleXMl objects. I found this http://www.mail-archive.com/fw-general@lists.zend.com/msg18133.html.

So it looks like I'll need to create some kind of custom frontend for Zend Cache to be able to change the serialize function used. Anybody ever done this already or can point me where to look to start?

Comment: Looks like Zend_Service_Twitter actually returns a Zend_Rest_Client_Result which then contains a SimpleXML object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to cache the SimpleXML object, I chose to loop through Twitter posts returned and save that data as a string. I then save that string to the cache. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can call **asXML()** function:

```
$simpleXml = @simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
$cache->save($simpleXml->asXML(), 'name_of_cache');
```

> Definition and Usage
>
> The asXML() function returns the XML document, from a SimpleXMLElement
>   object, as a string.
>   This function returns FALSE on failure.